# Why does this date format continue to change to 1970-01-01?

Tags: php, date

I am trying to convert the date 04/03/1992 to 1992-04-03 so I can insert it into a DATE formatted SQL Table.

Below is my PHP Code. For some reason only SOMETIMES it is converted to 1970-01-01

E.g. If i try to convert 13/04/2021 this prints out as 1970-01-01

Code below -

```
$date = $_POST["dateOfBirth"];
$dateToTime = strtotime($date);
$DOB = date("Y-m-d", $dateToTime);

$licenseNumber = $_POST["licenseNumber"];

$licenseDate = $_POST["licenseExpiryDate"];
$licenseDateToTime = strtotime($licenseDate);
$licenseExpiryDate = date('Y-m-d', $licenseDateToTime);
```

Comment: Because `13/04/2021` is `m/d/Y` and not `d/m/Y` as you expect. You know which month is the 13th?

Comment: `Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-), the date string is parsed as y-m-d.` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Read the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php  ... "Note:

Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed;"

Comment: You seemed to understand this, since you wrote that `04/03/1992` is `1992-04-03`. So that means that `13/04/2021` would be `2021-13-04`. And unless Trump is planning calendar reforms before he leaves office, there's no month 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strtotime function is sensitive to when you use forward slashes `/` and dashes `-`. Below is a quote from php.net to explain.

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.

Your date is in the european format so the simplest solution would be to replace the forward slashes `/` with dashes `-` using the `str_replace` function.

```
$date = str_replace("/","-",$_POST["dateOfBirth"]); $dateToTime = strtotime($date); $DOB = date("Y-m-d", $dateToTime);

$licenseNumber = $_POST["licenseNumber"];

$licenseDate = str_replace("/","-",$_POST["licenseExpiryDate"]); $licenseDateToTime = strtotime($licenseDate); $licenseExpiryDate = date('Y-m-d', $licenseDateToTime);
```

Comment: Thanks mate - unlike the rest of these useless responses this was perfect and exactly what I was looking for.

Much appreciated :) !